# How to flip column order in Word table depending on if page is odd or even

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I have a very long 2 column table in Word, which I need to print double-page. In odd pages, the column order must be **A B** and in even pages it must be **B A**, and it must be done automatically. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it, there is no such functionality in Word.

Your only option is to keep your tables separated by page and order columns manually.